# Prolog filter a list of all elements for which a custom goal fails

Tags: prolog, meta-predicate

I am trying to write a predicate `filter(List, PredName, Result)` that filters a `List` of all its elements for which the goal `PredName` fails and subsequently returns the `Result` list. The predicate `PredName/1` should be defined when calling the procedure `filter/3` and could for example be:

```
test(N) :- N >= 0
```

A query could then be made like following:

```
?- filter([-6,7,-1,0], test, L)
L = [7, 0];
no
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SWI-Prolog you could use the `exclude` predicate from the ["apply" library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/apply.html%27%29%29)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure a builtin operation exists to do this... but essentially you are just trying to do a findall on the member of the list that pass the predicate.  Try this implementation of filter out.  The second arg to findall is run until all results are exhausted and all values of M are collected into Result.

```
filter(List,PredName,Result) :-
  findall(M, ( member(M, List), call(PredName,M)), Result).
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to do that is using recursion and 'call' predicate

```
filter([],_,[]).
filter([H|T], PredName, [H|S]) :-  call(PredName,H),filter(T,PredName,S),!.
filter([H|T], PredName, S) :- filter(T,PredName,S).
```

other way to that is instead of call you can use `=..` (univ) operator.

```
filter([],_,[]).
filter2([H|T], PredName, [H|S]) :-  Goal =.. [PredName,H],Goal,filter(T,PredName,S),!.
filter([H|T], PredName, S) :- filter(T,PredName,S).
```

`=..` operator takes a list that contains predicate name and its arguments and returns newly created term. for example:

```
?-X =.. [f,a,b].
X = f(a, b).
```

Comment: Please note that using `(=..)/2` as you did, limits `PredName` to an atom. That means that Goal must be a predicate of arity 1. Using `call/2` you are much more flexible: You can now use any suitable predicate with arity >= 1. This is often very useful. See also @Nick Main's answer.

Comment: @false Can you give an example to clarify what you said?

Comment: A minimal example: Consider you want to filter out all elements `E` such that `E \== 3`. With `(=..)/2` you would have to define a new predicate `noteqeq3(E) :- E \== 3.` but with `call/2` you can hand over `\==(3)` directly.