# Use of Prolog =.. predicate

Tags: prolog, meta-predicate

I'm working on an exercise whereby I'm trying to use the =.. predicate to write a procedure that removes all elements in List for which PredName(X) fails and returns the remaining list as Result:

```
filter(List, PredName, Result)
```

In this case with PredName being defined as:

```
test(N) :- atom(N).
```

For example:

```
?- filter([a,b,-6,7,A,-1,0,B], test, L).
L = [a,b,-6,7,-1,0],
```

I've got the following, but I'm not sure why I keep getting false as a result when testing with the example above:

```
test(N):-
    atomic(N).
filter([], _, []).
filter2([H|T], PredName, [H|S]):-
    Goal =.. [PredName, H],Goal,filter(T, PredName, S),!.
filter([H|T], PredName, S) :-
    filter2(T, PredName, S).
```

I got the above code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682641/prolog-procedure-to-clean-list-of-elements-for-which-prednamex-fails/6683786#6683786).

Comment: The cut is misplaced.

Comment: You took the code from another answer, but you did not read my comments below it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to **compile** the code?

I get:

```
Clauses of filter/3 are not together in the source-file
```

Why? Because you need to decide how to call the predicate: **Either** `filter2/3` **or** `filter/3`. You are currently using both names.

Also, when you have code like:

```
Goal =.. [PredName, H],
Goal
```

Simply use **`call/2`** *instead*. For example, the above can be *equivalently* written as:

```
call(PredName, H)
```

In summary:

- decide on the predicate name and stick to it
- **don't** use `(=..)/2` for such cases
- **do** use `call/2`.

Comment: Yeah, compiled it. Got that until I compiled it a second time - didn't get it again. Also, I would use call/2 but the purpose of the exercise was to attempt it with =..

Comment: I'm knew that you had to use `(=..)/2`, but I still want to mention that `call/2` is more appropriate in this case, so that instructors who read this have a chance to give more useful exercises in the future. There are many good exercises where using `(=..)/2` does make sense, but this definitely isn't one of them.

Comment: Fair point. Thanks anyway - the changes you proposed do work.

Comment: @Zena: Note that with your current use of `(=..)/2`, you can only call predicates of arity 1. So you cannot call it with, say `>(1)`, thus `call(>(1), E)` and thus `>(1, E)` or simply `1 > E`. That's the big advantage of `call/2`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Had a problem with the naming that I didn't catch before.
Renamed filter2 to filter and it worked.

Comment: Rather than add this as an answer, you should accept mat's answer since he pointed out the naming issue.